# Raspbian: client: command not found - building PSOL

Tags: bash, nginx, path, raspbian, pagespeed

I wanted to update and optimize my nginx server today. After the apt-get update,upgrade and even dist-upgrade, I went on to building the Pagespeed module for nginx from Google:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

(Everything is done as su)

But in the end I got this error:

```
configuring additional modules
adding module in /var/www/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta //yes I stored it in my www folder, just temporary.
Architecture not supported: armv6l
something@something:~/nginx-1.7.6# sudo make
make: *** No rule to make target 'build', needed by 'default'.  Stop.
```

Too bad for ARM users, but according to:
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/398
It seems I have to follow these steps:
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/wiki/Building-PSOL-From-Source
And that should do it.

But running the first bash for building results in this:

```
something@something:~/mod_pagespeed# sudo client config http://modpagespeed.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.9.32.1/src/
sudo: client: command not found
```

I cannot find a solution for it, but in my google search I found that it might have something to do with my PATH variable, somehow?

Not that it should make any diffrence but, I am running raspbian with jessie instead of wheezy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo. That should be `sudo gclient config ...`

Comment: This was the issue, thank you. How ever, I have encountered another issue regarding a compilation error because of a missing file. I have opened an new question for this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496660/raspbian-pagespeed-nginx-compliation-error)