# Raspbian: PageSpeed (nginx) compliation error

Tags: nginx, raspbian, pagespeed

After executing the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cd ~/bin
svn co http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/depot_tools
mkdir ~/mod_pagespeed
cd ~/mod_pagespeed
gclient config http://modpagespeed.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.9.32.1/src/
gclient sync --force --jobs=1 # add --revision=xxxx for a specific svn revision
cd src/
make AR.host="$PWD/build/wrappers/ar.sh" \
   AR.target="$PWD/build/wrappers/ar.sh" \
   BUILDTYPE=Release \
   mod_pagespeed_test pagespeed_automatic_test
```

From:
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/wiki/Building-PSOL-From-Source

In order to make PageSpeed from Google work on the Raspberry, an ARM device, as stated here:
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/398

I ended up with the following error, after flawlessly running the commands before 'make'. There were no errors while executing 'make' until this:

```
CXX(host) out/Release/obj.host/protoc/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.o
LINK(host) out/Release/protoc
RULE _home_something_mod_pagespeed_src_net_instaweb_instaweb_gyp_instaweb_image_types_pb_target_genproto_0 out/Release/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.h
CXX(target) out/Release/obj.target/instaweb_image_types_pb/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.o
In file included from out/Release/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.cc:5:0:
out/Release/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.h:7:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
#include <string>
              ^
compilation terminated.
net/instaweb/instaweb_image_types_pb.target.mk:355: recipe for target 'out/Release/obj.target/instaweb_image_types_pb/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.o' failed
make: *** [out/Release/obj.target/instaweb_image_types_pb/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.o] Error 1
```

I have ran the commands above several times, and I only got this far.
And indeed, I can only find the following files:

```
    image_types.proto
    image_types.pb.h
    image_types.pb.cc
```

In the following directory, as seen in the error:

```
/home/something/mod_pagespeed/src/out/Release/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter
```

How can I possibly retrieve the correct file necessary?

Answer (score 0):

To successfully pass the HTTPS fetching tests, you may need to first set environment variables to find the certificate files. On Ubuntu, the test binaries should have the correct paths by default. On CentOS, these settings should work:

export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/pki/tls/certs
  export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem